# Perl PSGI does not serve static files automatically

Tags: perl, psgi

I am practicing with Perl and PSGI/Plack. Just trying the simple PSGI example app:

app.psgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $counter = 0;

my $app = sub {
    my $env = shift;
    my $path = $env->{PATH_INFO} || $env->{REQUEST_URI};
    $counter++;
    my $content = "Hellow world.\nCounter=$counter\nPath: $path\n";
    return [ 200, [ 'Content-type', 'text/plain' ], [ $content ] ]
};
```

then run it by:

```
plackup app.psgi
```

if I point the browser to any path like /news/world:

```
http://localhost:5000/new/world
```

this is ok, I get the $path variable set to /news/world and I will handle the cgi response.

the problem if I point to static files like logo.png

```
http://localhost:5000/logo.png
```

I also get the $path variable set to /logo.png

The question is, why the plackup server does not serve the static image file logo.png automatically.

Do I have to do this manually? if so does that means on every request I have to ping the file system first check if -f $path.

This means I am building a complete server handler not just my script handler. What I am not understanding.

Comment: http://advent.plackperl.org/2009/12/day-17-serving-static-files-from-your-application.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Plack::Middleware::Static](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack%3A%3AMiddleware%3A%3AStatic) module. It allows your app to serve static files from root directory.

Answer (score 0):

`Plack::Middleware::Static` works for static directory. But you can process File Handler instead. You can try to put in the body the GLOB scalar and header `application/pdf`.